# How do I present a transparent UINavigationController + root modally?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In my TabBarController, I'm presenting a UINavigationController as a modal.  Once I present it, I'd like everything to be transparent (including the navigation bar).  However, I'd like everything **after** the root controller to be opaque.

```
            let transVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TransparentViewController") as! TransparentViewController
            transVC.delegate = self
            transVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            transVC.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext
            self.navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: transVC)  
            self.navController?.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext
            self.presentViewController(self.navController!, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Later, I will push other view controllers onto the stack. I want them to be opaque.

```
let messageVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
self.navController!.pushViewController(messageVC, animated: false) //should be opaque
```

If there is no sure way to do this, maybe we can take a screenshot of the app and set it as the background, as a workaround? How would I do that?

Comment: When you say your want a "transparent" navigation bar, do you mean no background or completely hidden?

Comment: @BradzTech it doens't matter - I just want everything transparent. No background (or hidden) is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, taking a screenshot is not necessary for a modally presented view controller to have a transparent background. Just present the segue using the presentation style of `.OverFullScreen` or `.OverCurrentContext`, rather than `.CurrentContext`, and ensure the view controller has a clear colored background.

Also, make sure you are setting the modalPresentation style of the navigation controller since that is what you are presenting, and therefore what will be used by the modal segue:

```
navController?.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen
```

### Auto-(un)hiding Navigation Bar

For the navigation bar to be hidden on the navigation controller's root view controller, I would subclass the root view controller so that when it appears, the navigation bar is hidden. When it disappears, the navigation bar should be unhidden.

In TransVC:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

Because it can be animated, `setNavigationBarHidden` integrates seamlessly with `pushViewController`. Alternatively, you could move the line that unhides the navigation bar to the viewWillAppear method in the view controller you are presenting.